# SharePoint-View: "This column type cannot be filtered"

Tags: sharepoint

Hallo,

i've got a list in a SharePoint-Website (WSS 3.0 SP1) that has a few lookup columns -
and i can filter the view of that list by some of that lookup columns, but not by all of them.
When i click the column-header in the view i can filter the view by the lookup-values - but some columns display the entry "This column type cannot be filtered" (grayed out) where the filter-options should be.

I do not see why this happens; this does happen if the lookup-field is a required field or not, and even if the 'Title' is the column to look up.

Any idea why this happens? What can i do to prevent this behavior?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kpinhack,

Without knowing how your fields/columns were created and deployed (and at the risk of oversimplifying), it could be as simple as the fields themselves not being marked as "Filterable":

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.filterable.aspx

Each **SPField** type has a **Filterable** boolean property that can (obviously) be set to TRUE or FALSE.  If the property is "FALSE," then the field can't be used for filtering operations.

Whether the **Filterable** property is set to TRUE or FALSE on an **SPField** is going to be a function of how the developer defined it.  If the fields were created by custom code/CAML, then that code or CAML could be modified to set the property value to TRUE.

For what it's worth!

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to say what is causing it in your situation.

Here is a walk through on how to connect a filter web part to a data web part:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointserver/HA102509971033.aspx

Do the columns that cannot be filtered have something in common?

Answer (score 0):

This is (usually) also the case when the column is a compound column, like the Name field in a publishing Pages library.